# E/CheckPermission: Permission Denial: can't use real_camera takePicture

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, background-service, oppo

I have an application which takes a photo by launching the activity from background whenever the user sends the message(FCM)

In most of the devices, it works perfectly but in oppo phones I am getting below error when phone screen is locked otherwise it is working fine.

```
 E/CheckPermission: real_camera-code= 9
OppoPermissionInterceptPolicy: Reject background permission android.permission.CAMERApkgName: Packagename
 W/ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.CAMERA_TAKEPICTURE from uid=10681 pid=7165
    E/CheckPermission: Permission Denial: can't use real_camera takePicture
```

How can I prevent this issue?
I want to take a photo even if the phone is locked

**Note:** Every camera permission is set, app is working fine in all phones other than OPPO

Comment: take photo, even if the phone is locked? Is that even possible, if possible is that even legal?

Comment: yes, there are so many applications on play store doing it
But this is not my question, thanks

Comment: have you found any answer? @AminPinjari